# Linux Mint gcc++ : can't install gcc++ because of broken packages

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, gcc

I am a student of CS and new to Linux Mint 18.2.
I am trying to run a simple project in Clion but apparently I have a problem with my gcc++ compiler.

I try to run this command in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc++
```

and gets the following:

```
    Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.9-hppa-linux-gnu' for regex 'gcc+'
Note, selecting 'libsfgcc1-dbg-armhf-cross' for regex 'gcc+'
```

Long list of Note, selecting ......
and the end of this is:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gcc-4.7-plugin-dev : Depends: libgmpv4-dev (>= 2:5.0.1~) but it is not going to be installed
 gcc-4.8-aarch64-linux-gnu : Conflicts: gcc-multilib but 4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
 gcc-4.8-arm-linux-gnueabihf : Conflicts: gcc-multilib but 4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
 gcc-4.8-multilib : Depends: libc6-dev-x32 (>= 2.11) but it is not going to be installed
 gcc-4.8-powerpc-linux-gnu : Conflicts: gcc-multilib but 4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
 gcc-4.8-powerpc64le-linux-gnu : Conflicts: gcc-multilib but 4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
 gcc-4.9-aarch64-linux-gnu : Conflicts: gcc-multilib but 4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
 gcc-4.9-arm-linux-gnueabi : Conflicts: gcc-multilib but 4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
 gcc-4.9-arm-linux-gnueabihf : Conflicts: gcc-multilib but 4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
 gcc-4.9-multilib : Depends: libc6-dev-x32 (>= 2.11) but it is not going to be installed
 gcc-4.9-powerpc-linux-gnu : Conflicts: gcc-multilib but 4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
 gcc-4.9-powerpc64le-linux-gnu : Conflicts: gcc-multilib but 4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
 gcc-4.9-s390x-linux-gnu : Conflicts: gcc-multilib but 4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
 gcc-5-aarch64-linux-gnu : Conflicts: gcc-multilib but 4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
 gcc-5-alpha-linux-gnu : Conflicts: gcc-multilib but 4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
 gcc-5-arm-linux-gnueabi : Conflicts: gcc-multilib but 4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
 gcc-5-arm-linux-gnueabihf : Conflicts: gcc-multilib but 4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
 gcc-5-hppa-linux-gnu : Conflicts: gcc-multilib but 4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
 gcc-5-m68k-linux-gnu : Conflicts: gcc-multilib but 4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
 gcc-5-mips-linux-gnu : Conflicts: gcc-multilib but 4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
 gcc-5-mips64-linux-gnuabi64 : Conflicts: gcc-multilib but 4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
 gcc-5-mips64el-linux-gnuabi64 : Conflicts: gcc-multilib but 4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
 gcc-5-mipsel-linux-gnu : Conflicts: gcc-multilib but 4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
 gcc-5-multilib : Depends: libc6-dev-x32 (>= 2.11) but it is not going to be installed
 gcc-5-powerpc-linux-gnu : Conflicts: gcc-multilib but 4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
 gcc-5-powerpc-linux-gnuspe : Conflicts: gcc-multilib but 4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
 gcc-5-powerpc64-linux-gnu : Conflicts: gcc-multilib but 4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
 gcc-5-powerpc64le-linux-gnu : Conflicts: gcc-multilib but 4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
 gcc-5-s390x-linux-gnu : Conflicts: gcc-multilib but 4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
 gcc-5-sh4-linux-gnu : Conflicts: gcc-multilib but 4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
 gcc-5-sparc64-linux-gnu : Conflicts: gcc-multilib but 4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
 gcc-multilib : Conflicts: gcc-4.9-aarch64-linux-gnu but 4.9.3-13ubuntu2cross1 is to be installed
                Conflicts: gcc-4.9-arm-linux-gnueabi but 4.9.3-13ubuntu2cross1 is to be installed
                Conflicts: gcc-4.9-arm-linux-gnueabihf but 4.9.3-13ubuntu2cross1 is to be installed
                Conflicts: gcc-4.9-powerpc-linux-gnu but 4.9.3-13ubuntu2cross1 is to be installed
                Conflicts: gcc-4.9-powerpc64le-linux-gnu but 4.9.3-13ubuntu2cross1 is to be installed
                Conflicts: gcc-4.9-s390x-linux-gnu but 4.9.3-13ubuntu2cross1 is to be installed
                Conflicts: gcc-5-aarch64-linux-gnu
                Conflicts: gcc-5-alpha-linux-gnu
                Conflicts: gcc-5-arm-linux-gnueabi
                Conflicts: gcc-5-arm-linux-gnueabihf
                Conflicts: gcc-5-hppa-linux-gnu
                Conflicts: gcc-5-m68k-linux-gnu
                Conflicts: gcc-5-mips-linux-gnu
                Conflicts: gcc-5-mips64-linux-gnuabi64
                Conflicts: gcc-5-mips64el-linux-gnuabi64
                Conflicts: gcc-5-mipsel-linux-gnu
                Conflicts: gcc-5-powerpc-linux-gnu
                Conflicts: gcc-5-powerpc-linux-gnuspe
                Conflicts: gcc-5-powerpc64-linux-gnu
                Conflicts: gcc-5-powerpc64le-linux-gnu
                Conflicts: gcc-5-s390x-linux-gnu
                Conflicts: gcc-5-sh4-linux-gnu
                Conflicts: gcc-5-sparc64-linux-gnu
                Conflicts: gcc-5-aarch64-linux-gnu:i386
                Conflicts: gcc-5-arm-linux-gnueabihf:i386
                Conflicts: gcc-5-powerpc-linux-gnu:i386
                Conflicts: gcc-5-powerpc64le-linux-gnu:i386
                Conflicts: gcc-5-alpha-linux-gnu:i386
                Conflicts: gcc-5-arm-linux-gnueabi:i386
                Conflicts: gcc-5-hppa-linux-gnu:i386
                Conflicts: gcc-5-m68k-linux-gnu:i386
                Conflicts: gcc-5-mips-linux-gnu:i386
                Conflicts: gcc-5-mips64-linux-gnuabi64:i386
                Conflicts: gcc-5-mips64el-linux-gnuabi64:i386
                Conflicts: gcc-5-mipsel-linux-gnu:i386
                Conflicts: gcc-5-powerpc-linux-gnuspe:i386
                Conflicts: gcc-5-powerpc64-linux-gnu:i386
                Conflicts: gcc-5-s390x-linux-gnu:i386
                Conflicts: gcc-5-sh4-linux-gnu:i386
                Conflicts: gcc-5-sparc64-linux-gnu:i386
 gcc-snapshot : Depends: libc6-dev-x32 (>= 2.11) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libc6-x32 (>= 2.23) but it is not going to be installed
 gccgo-4.7-multilib : Depends: libx32go0 (>= 4.7.4-3ubuntu12) but it is not going to be installed
 gccgo-4.8-multilib : Depends: libx32go4 (>= 4.8.5-4ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
 gccgo-4.9-multilib : Depends: libx32go5 (>= 4.9.3-13ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
 gccgo-5-multilib : Depends: libx32go7 (>= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) but it is not going to be installed
 gccgo-6-multilib : Depends: libx32go9 (>= 6.0.1-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
 lib32gcc-4.7-dev : Depends: libx32gomp1 (>= 4.7.4-3ubuntu12) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libx32itm1 (>= 4.7.4-3ubuntu12) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libx32quadmath0 (>= 4.7.4-3ubuntu12) but it is not going to be installed
 lib32gcc-4.8-dev : Depends: libx32gomp1 (>= 4.8.5-4ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libx32itm1 (>= 4.8.5-4ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libx32atomic1 (>= 4.8.5-4ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libx32asan0 (>= 4.8.5-4ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libx32quadmath0 (>= 4.8.5-4ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
 lib32gcc-4.9-dev : Depends: libx32gomp1 (>= 4.9.3-13ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libx32itm1 (>= 4.9.3-13ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libx32atomic1 (>= 4.9.3-13ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libx32asan1 (>= 4.9.3-13ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libx32ubsan0 (>= 4.9.3-13ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libx32cilkrts5 (>= 4.9.3-13ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libx32quadmath0 (>= 4.9.3-13ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
 lib32gcc-5-dev : Depends: libx32gomp1 (>= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libx32itm1 (>= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libx32atomic1 (>= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libx32asan2 (>= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libx32ubsan0 (>= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libx32cilkrts5 (>= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libx32quadmath0 (>= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) but it is not going to be installed
 lib64gcc-4.7-dev:i386 : Depends: libx32gcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.7.4-3ubuntu12) but it is not going to be installed
 lib64gcc-4.8-dev:i386 : Depends: libx32gcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.8.5-4ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libx32asan0:i386 (>= 4.8.5-4ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
 lib64gcc-4.9-dev:i386 : Depends: libx32gcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.9.3-13ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libx32asan1:i386 (>= 4.9.3-13ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libx32ubsan0:i386 (>= 4.9.3-13ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libx32cilkrts5:i386 (>= 4.9.3-13ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
 lib64gcc-5-dev:i386 : Depends: libx32gcc1:i386 (>= 1:5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libx32asan2:i386 (>= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libx32ubsan0:i386 (>= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libx32cilkrts5:i386 (>= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) but it is not going to be installed
 libx32gcc-4.7-dev : Depends: libx32gomp1 (>= 4.7.4-3ubuntu12) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libx32itm1 (>= 4.7.4-3ubuntu12) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libx32quadmath0 (>= 4.7.4-3ubuntu12) but it is not going to be installed
 libx32gcc-4.8-dev : Depends: libx32gomp1 (>= 4.8.5-4ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libx32itm1 (>= 4.8.5-4ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libx32atomic1 (>= 4.8.5-4ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libx32asan0 (>= 4.8.5-4ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libx32quadmath0 (>= 4.8.5-4ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
 libx32gcc-4.9-dev : Depends: libx32gomp1 (>= 4.9.3-13ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libx32itm1 (>= 4.9.3-13ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libx32atomic1 (>= 4.9.3-13ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libx32asan1 (>= 4.9.3-13ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libx32ubsan0 (>= 4.9.3-13ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libx32cilkrts5 (>= 4.9.3-13ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libx32quadmath0 (>= 4.9.3-13ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
 libx32gcc-5-dev : Depends: libx32gomp1 (>= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libx32itm1 (>= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libx32atomic1 (>= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libx32asan2 (>= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libx32ubsan0 (>= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libx32cilkrts5 (>= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libx32quadmath0 (>= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) but it is not going to be installed
 libx32gcc1 : Depends: libc6-x32 (>= 2.16) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: There is no such thing as `gcc++`.  There is a `gcc`, and a `g++`.

Comment: You probably want to install the `build-essential` package - it will bring in g++ and other compilers and utilities needed.  For stuff that is essential to building code :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to install the `g++` package:

```
sudo apt install g++
```

(Trying to install `gcc++` produces the strange results you’re getting because `gcc++` doesn’t match a package name, so `apt-get` interprets it as a regex and tries to install all the matching packages, which it can’t because they conflict with each other.)

Comment: after that: sudo apt install g++ (which I did right now)
should I do another thing?

Comment: No, `sudo apt install g++` is all you need to run to install the GCC C++ compiler.

Comment: so do you have any idea what causes this error in Clion? :


'- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- broken
CMake Error at /home/ori/Downloads/clion-2017.2.3/bin/cmake/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:51 (message):
  The C compiler "/usr/bin/cc" is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/ori/CLionProjects/Try2/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

Comment: I suggest you [ask that as a new question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) with the complete output.